# Fullcalendar timezone option is ignored

Tags: timezone, fullcalendar

I am fighting with the timezone option of fullCalendar plugin. It doesn't matter what I set: none, UTC or a specific location, everything is ignored by the plugin. All given times are shown as UTC+2 (Thats my location). What i do:

First creating some events according following code:

```
if(!newsCalendarEvent){
    var newsCalendarEvent = [];
}
newsCalendarEvent["Event_1"] = {
    events: [
        {
            title: 'my first news',
            start: '2015-08-02T17:46:00Z',
            end: '2015-08-10T17:46:00Z',
            className: 'Event_1'

        }
    ],
    color: '',
    textColor: ''
}
```

Then creating the calendar and looping through these events:

```
newsCalendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    lang: 'de',
                    buttonIcons: false, // show the prev/next text
                    weekNumbers: true,

                    timezone : 'none',
                    timeFormat: 'H(:mm)'

                })

            for (var key in newsCalendarEvent) {
              if (newsCalendarEvent.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                newsCalendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', newsCalendarEvent[key] )   
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem had nothing to do with this plugin. It has been a qustion of timesetting in my php code.